# "This happened" or "This happens"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, sequence-of-tenses

Here is my sentence

> She wanted to show us something, then this happened/happens.

I used grammar checker but it doesn't tell me which one should I use. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If *wanted* is used with *happens*, then the verbs in the sentence are mixing tenses in a way that's somewhat unusual. It's not necessarily wrong in the right context, but looking only at the sentence itself, the tenses would normally be kept the same:

- She **wanted** to show us something, [and] then this **happened**.
- She **wants** to show us something, [and] then this **happens**.

Generally speaking, more narrative takes place in the past tense than the present tense. So, it would be more common to see *wanted* and *happened* used together.

However, it really depends on the tenses being used in the rest of the narrative, and how events are being described in relation to each other.